# Error importing airport names using django-airport

Tags: python, django, import, django-views

I have installed and configured both [django-cities](https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities) and [django-airport](https://github.com/bashu/django-airports). But i am getting error while importing airport data via this command -

```
./manage.py airports
```

The error is -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                   
File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>                                                                                                           
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)                                                                                                              
File "/home/itsd/venv/mnq_v2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line               
utility.execute()                                                                                                                                
File "/home/itsd/venv/mnq_v2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute                                 
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)                                                                                          
File "/home/itsd/venv/mnq_v2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 208, in fetch_command                           
klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)                                                                                                 
File "/home/itsd/venv/mnq_v2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 40, in load_command_class                       
module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))                                                                           
File "/home/itsd/venv/mnq_v2/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module                                                      
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)                                                                                      
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import                                                                                     
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load                                                                                  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked                                                                         
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked                                                                                  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module                                                                            
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed                                                                       
File "/home/itsd/venv/mnq_v2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airports/management/commands/airports.py", line 29, in <module>                           
class Command(BaseCommand):                                                                                                                      
File "/home/itsd/venv/mnq_v2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airports/management/commands/airports.py", line 35, in Command                            
option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (                                                                                                        
AttributeError: type object 'BaseCommand' has no attribute 'option_list'
```

How can i solve this problem ?

My Django version is - 1.10.4

Comment: `BaseCommand.option_list` was removed in Django 1.10. If there is not a newer version of `django-airport` available, the ony option would be to downgrade to an earlier version of Django.

Comment: That will be difficult for me as my project is almost finished. Are there any alternative to get airport names?

Comment: I don't know anything about airport names. Maybe Google or someone else can help. Or try `pip install django==1.9.13`, unless you're using any new features of 1.10.